# Drop User from Group

Tags: sql-server

I have a group in SQL Server called IT1. I want to delete one user from that group. I tried `DROP USER [HDDomain\UserName]` but

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
> Cannot drop the user 'HDDomain\UserName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Drop User command in T-SQL

Comment: To remove a Windows user from an AD group, you need to do that in Windows rather than T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember 'HDDomain\UserName', 'IT1'
```